# dump array in php, how to retrieve the value from array

Tags: php

```
var_dump($products);
```

Output: `array(7) { [0]=> array(5) { ["Product"]=> array(40) { ["id"]=> string(3) "726"  ["wbb"]=> string(1) "1" ["abb"]=> string(1) "0" }`

But when I do `var_dump($products['Product']['wbb']);` it gives me NULL

How I will use the value of ["wbb"]

```
if(!empty($product)) :
```

If i dump $product, it gives me different products with details of each product.
Simple output of one product when I dump $product

```
array(7) { [0]=> array(5) { ["Product"]=> array(40) { ["id"]=> string(3) "726" ["wbb"]=> string(1) "1" ["abb"]=> string(1) "0" }

{ [1]=> array(5) { ["Product"]=> array(40) { ["id"]=> string(3) "727" ["wbb"]=> string(1) "0" ["abb"]=> string(1) "1" }
```

Similarly I have 10 more products with some of them are wbb = 1 and some of them are abb =1. I want to add tooltip according to the flag raised. But when I do like this 
$i++;

```
if(!empty($product[$i]['Product']['wbb'])){ echo code here.....}
```

becuase it iterates, so it will not give me according to exact product. How should I have to do it?

Comment: $products[0]['Product']['wbb']

Comment: And where does the `$product` variable come from? Do you foreach over your `$products`? Please share *all* relevant code, otherwise we can't help you!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you should be using `var_dump($products[0]['Product']['wbb']);`

Answer (score 2):

If you look closely you will notice that the `$products` array is a multidimensional array, holding a numeric key for each data row (starting at 0). Any additional rows will get 1, 2 and so on. In order to get the mentioned `wbb` value of the first (and apparently only) row, use

```
var_dump($products[0]['Product']['wbb']);
```

Instead.

Comment: @AbrarKiyani In that case you have not shown us all your code. If I recreate the array as you pasted it and use the variable above, this code example outputs `WBB is 1`, as would be expected: https://gist.github.com/oldskool/5144154

Answer (score 2):

`$products` is an array of multiple products. You should use:

```
var_dump($products[0]['Product']['wbb']);
```

Comment: And what would you call `$products` if the [0] key wasn't there? It's still an array regardless, this one is just multidimensional and numerically indexed per result row.